# SQL Server decimal rounding issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to restrict the numbers to 4 decimal places while rounding the 4th decimal number in the Col1. But none of the below functions is doing it.

```
select 
a + ISNULL(b,0) + ISNULL(c, 0) as col1,
convert(money, a + ISNULL(b,0) + ISNULL(c, 0)) as col2,
convert(decimal(19, 4), a + ISNULL(b,0) + ISNULL(c, 0)) as col3,
round(a + ISNULL(b,0) + ISNULL(c, 0),4) as col4
from table1
```

Actual result:

```
col1            col2          col3          col4
170932.96505    170932.965    170932.9650   170932.965
293944.57535    293944.5753   293944.5753   293944.5753
116913.64795    116913.6479   116913.6479   116913.6479
15975.13135     15975.1313    15975.1313    15975.1313
```

Expected result (in col2/col3/col4):

```
170932.9651
293944.5754
116913.6480
15975.1314
```

Table structure:

```
create table test(
a money,
b float,
c money
);
```

Example record:

```
insert into test values (15541.55, 23.57135, 410.01);
```

Comment: Please don't [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75802041/sql-server-decimal-rounding-issue) and repost questions. There is an edit feature, use that.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I wasn't aware. @ThomA

Comment: `col3` looks fine to me. What's the issue? We can't run your query, as we have no sample data.

Comment: What are the column types of `a`, `b` and `c`? If you start off with floating-point numbers you can throw in `money` and `decimal` all you like, but getting correctly rounded results will take some more finesse depending on what the original values are in the first place.

Comment: If your question is closed for some reason, try to improve it so it doesn't get closed one more time.

Comment: Almost certainly a `float` based on the varying number of decimal places when `ROUND` is used, @JeroenMostert , which as I stated in their deleted question is very likely that is the start of their problems.

Comment: @JeroenMostert a `money`, b `float`, c `money`

Comment: you can try in this way SELECT ROUND(a + ISNULL(b,0) + ISNULL(c, 0) as col1, 4) AS Col1;

Comment: Right, and why is `b` a `float` -- any case that needs fixing in an earlier stage? In some sense there is no "correct" answer when you start adding numbers that have no exact representations in decimal to numbers that do.

Comment: @dtc348 col4 is doing it.

Comment: does it have to be a float? consider changing the type to decimal, it would probably solve your issue

Comment: Converting `b` to `money`/`decimal` while adding with `a` and `c` did not yield the expected result.

Comment: @athresh Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So include the data you use for your example so we can run it yourself. What rounding convention do you mean to use?

Comment: https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/

Comment: @MarkBaijens I've added to my question.

Comment: Your problem is that `23.57135` cannot be represented exactly as a `FLOAT`. The actual value is more along the lines of `23.571349999999999...` Rounding this directly to four digits will result in `23.5713`. The best way of tackling this problem is to ensure your data never ends up as a `FLOAT` to begin with. If this is not an option, use a higher intermediate precision before rounding -- `SELECT CONVERT(MONEY, $15541.55 + CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 5), 23.57135e) + $410.01)` gives the desired result. Depending on what your calculations could yield, you may need more than 5 digits.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Your query is adding 2 money values with a float value. Based on the rules of data type precedence, the money values will be converted to float, and then the addition will occur.

[Problems with money data type](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/avoid-use-money-smallmoney-datatypes)

[Problems with the float data type](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/the-dangers-of-using-float-or-real-datatypes)

The money data type can lead to rounding errors and the float data type only stores approximate values (as mentioned in the comments). Personally, I would ALWAYS avoid using the money data type, and I would only use the float data type if I cared about approximate values with widely varying precisions.

Regardless, if you cannot change the data types for your columns, you should expect to sometimes get rounding errors. If you cannot change the data types in your tables, you can at least change the data types for the purposes of your query. Since you want 4 digits of precision, I would suggest that you use decimal(20,5) or decimal(21,6) within your query (depending on the number of values you are adding together).

For example:

```
Declare @Test table (
a money,
b float,
c money
);

insert into @test values (15541.55, 23.57135, 410.01);

select  Round(Convert(Decimal(20,5), a) + Convert(Decimal(20,5), b) + Convert(Decimal(20,5), c), 4),
        Convert(Decimal(20,4),  Convert(Decimal(20,5), a) +
                                Convert(Decimal(20,5), b) +
                                Convert(Decimal(20,5), c))
from    @Test
```

The idea here is to use a higher precision for all the calculations and then convert to a lower precision at the very end. Since you are starting with "bad" data types, rounding errors can still occur, but this method should reduce the rounding errors for you.